# What is the standard ASP.net data binding syntax?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, databinder

Microsoft's introduction to [data-binding using the `asp:Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx) control gives the syntax to fetch a value:

```
<b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "orderid") %></b>
```

This syntax is repeated on [other introductions to the ASP.net `Repeater` control](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/controls/article.php/c19299/The-ASPNET-Repeater-Web-Server-Control.htm):

```
<a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>">...</a>
```

But i remember this syntax being "bad" and "wrong". From the MSDN documentation of [`DataBinder.Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) i see:

> [image]    **Note**
>
> Because this method performs late-bound evaluation, using reflection at run time, it can cause performance to noticeably slow compared to **standard ASP.NET data-binding syntax**.

*(emphases added)*

So that explains *why* i had a memory of *"`Eval` is bad"*. But what ***is*** the "standard ASP.NET data-binding syntax"?

### Bonus Reading

- [Data-Binding Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just do a cast to avoid the "late binding" penalty:

```
<%# (((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["URL"]) %>
```

Now let's say you increase performance by x%.  Is it worth it to your application?  The trade-off (in my opinion) is less readability.

Answer (score 1):

Well "standard ASP.NET data-binding" generally refers to binding data from a data source to named controls, such as the textboxes on a form, or the old GridView where you can bind an entire table.

If you just need a read only display of data, you might consider a foreach loop or a DataReader to parse the data into raw HTML in a stringBuilder and then dump the StringBuilder into a Literal.

Comment: i was doing that (building the html i want). But then it was suggested that i make it "better", using nested repeaters to get something *close* to the html i want. Which is why i had to ask about binding syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.71).aspx) describes standard databinding syntax as follows:

> In the following code fragment, for example, an integer is displayed as a currency string. **With the standard ASP.NET data-binding syntax**, you must first cast the type of the data row in order to retrieve the data field, IntegerValue. Next, this is passed as an argument to the String.Format method:
>
> ```
> <%# String.Format("{0:c}", ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["IntegerValue"]) %>
> ```